# How to parse GeoJSON with Ruby and save coordinates to .csv file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, geojson

I want to parse a GeoJSON file (Point type) and save the coordinates (lat/lng) to .CSV file. How to do this with Ruby? Following is a GeoJSON file. Thanks in advance!

```
{  "type": "FeatureCollection",  
    "features": [
{ "type": "Feature",
  "id": 1,
  "properties": {
    "cluster": {
      "x": -0.229559,
      "y": 0.270089
    }
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -74.1518294,
      40.5793043
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 2,
  "properties": {
    "cluster": {
      "x": 0.00379515,
      "y": 0.121912
    }
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -74.0818064,
      40.9278118
    ]
  }
}, ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`rgeo-geojson` gem](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-geojson) to do it:

```
require 'rgeo/geo_json'
require 'csv'

points = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(json, json_parser: :json) # json must be a string here

CSV.open("points.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["x", "y"]
  points.each do |point|
    csv << [point.geometry.x, point.geometry.y]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want storing lat and lng in csv file,

```
$ cat geo.json 
{  "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
{ 
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 1,
  "properties": {
    "cluster": {
      "x": -0.229559,
      "y": 0.270089
    }
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -74.1518294,
      40.5793043
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 2,
  "properties": {
    "cluster": {
      "x": 0.00379515,
      "y": 0.121912
    }
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -74.0818064,
      40.9278118
    ]
  }
}  
]
  }
```

ruby script

```
require 'json'
require 'csv'

q = h['features'].map {|e| e['geometry']['coordinates'] }
#=> [[-74.1518294, 40.5793043], [-74.0818064, 40.9278118]]
CSV.open('coords.csv', 'wb') {|csv| q.each {|e|csv << e }}
```

contents of csv file.

```
$ cat coords.csv 
-74.1518294,40.5793043
-74.0818064,40.9278118
```

If you also want to store ids, change

```
q = h["features"].map {|e| [e['id'], e['geometry']['coordinates']].flatten }
```

if you want to write headers,

```
CSV.open('coords.csv', "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ['ID', 'LAT', 'LNG']
  q.each {|e|csv << e }
end
```

contents of coords

```
$ cat coords.csv 
ID,LAT,LNG
1,-74.1518294,40.5793043
2,-74.0818064,40.9278118
```

Comment: I solved my problem by using online tools that convert GeoJSON to CSV. But your approach will be very convenient  when I have many GeoJSON files. Thanks!